# laravel model accessors not working in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, accessor

the attribute (full name in this instance) does not show up when using User::find(1); (which actually returns an user instance) and dd("test") inside the accessor is also not called

i've dd'd the model using tinker and i've tried using dd on the $request->user() output returns the same.

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable,HasApiTokens;


    protected $hidden = [
       'id',
        'master_password',
        'remember_token',
        'provider',
        'provider_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        dd("test");
        return "test";
    }

}
```

i expect the user attribute with the field full_name returning "test". (or a dump and die if you let the dd in.)

Comment: You actually have to call the accessor via `$user->full_name`; currently, it's just a function, and functions aren't generally called until explicitly told to do so. Or, add it to the `$appends` property: `protected $appends = ["full_name"];`

Comment: this does not 

protected $appends = ['test'];

public function getTestAttribute()
    {
        return "test";
   }
it still shows no test field in my attributes

Comment: That might just be for when converting to `json`. No biggie. Does `$user->full_name` (or `$user->test`) trigger it though? That was the main point of the comment.

Comment: yes it does but it does not show me the attribute which i need

Comment: What do you mean? If it shows `"test"`, it works... The attribute is available if you need it via `$user->full_name;` what's the issue? You probably need to show how you're using `$user`; are you passing it to a view? Sending via an api?

Comment: what i want is that i can return it through an api, by calling User::find(1) f/e then it should show the test accessor in the User instance too but it does not.

[!] Aliasing 'User' to 'App\User' for this Tinker session.
=> App\User {#3042
     display_name: "sdfsdf",
     user_email: "sdfsdfsdf",
     email_verified_at: null,
     icon_url: "dfgdfg",
   }

Comment: If you put `full_name` is `$appends`, then return the user via `json` (`return response()->json($user);`), then `user.full_name` would be available. I'm not sure why this is the case in `Tinker` (don't personally use it), but yeah. If you have access to `$user` in `Laravel`, you don't need to worry about it being present or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to laravel docs:

> Once the attribute has been added to the appends list, it will be included in both the model's array and JSON forms. Attributes in the appends array will also respect the visible and hidden settings configured on the model.

The `test` attribute will not appear within `$attributes` until you call  the `toArray()` or `toJson()` functions.

The `User` instance attributes array are not an array representation of the User class.

If you are working with a `User` object, then you can get the accessor attributes using $user->test.

If you want the array or json representation of the `User` object, then return it as an array/json `$user->toArray()` or `$user->toJson()` - now accessors included in the `$appends` array will automatically be included.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this in your model:

```
protected $appends = ['full_name'];
```

And it will call your getFullNameAttribute and add it by default. It was introduced especially for api building.